# SQL how to do a LIKE search on each value of a declared variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, sql-like, declare

I have a query where I am trying to do a LIKE search on each value of a declared variable, instead of doing a like search on the entire field value/string.

**Example:**

```
    DECLARE @name VARCHAR(30)
    SET @name = 'John Smith'
    SELECT name FROM customers WHERE name like '%'+ @name + '%'
```

The record I am looking for is "John and Jane Smith". The query above returns NO result. If the user searches just 'John' OR just 'Smith' there are too many results returned.

I am trying to get the query to search like the query below:

```
    SELECT name from customers WHERE name LIKE '%John%  %Smith%'
```

I've searched for many options but not sure if my search terms are not correct, I have yet to find a solution.

Comment: You might be better off using FTS instead of creating a query with LIKE clauses where the leading and trailing characters are wild cards. That said the result you want would be `SELECT name from customers WHERE name LIKE '%John%' AND name LIKE '%Smith%'` unless the order of terms matters.

Comment: Igor my first option was to use the CONTAINS but don't have a full-text index on this table.
don't think I'll get it either.

Comment: Igor, I could use this as well right?
        SELECT name from customers WHERE name LIKE '%John%  %Smith%' to get the same result?

Comment: No the result *could* be different depending on the input. If the name was entered/stored as last name, first name your query would not pull back anything but mine would. Also your query requires there is a space between the 2 names in the field.

Comment: Ok understood, thank you for that information, I did not know that.

Comment: Sounds like the real problem is that you should be designing your system so that multiple people can be linked to a single customer account. And, also, storing Title, First Name, Middle Name(s) and Surname separately.

Comment: @Larnu the system is designed that way, but there is one field that a general "Contact Name" and for family ran businesses, the contact name is entered as multiple people

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't mean it should; coming from someone who works for a business that designed their system like that and quickly showed them why it was a bad idea. Because they ask exactly the type of questions you are, and `'John Smith' != 'John and Jane Smith'`

Comment: @Larnu I agree, there are always better options and reasons why certain things should not be done. Case in point, this post.
Thank you for the advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try replacing spaces in your `@name` with `'% %'`
Something like

```
SET @nameFilter = REPLACE(@name,' ','% %')
SELECT name FROM customers WHERE name like '%'+ @ nameFilter + '%'
```

Comment: I did try using REPLACE() on the spaces but it got kind of ugly, wasn't sure how to accomplish it. Can you supply an example?

Comment: @Larnu do you have an example of the REPLACE mentioned above? I want to try this option

Comment: @sugar2code This worked thank you! I moved the replace down into the where clause where name variable is stated and worked great.

Answer (score 1):

A full-text search seems like the best approach.  But you can approximate this at the word level by splitting the search term and looking for each individual word:

```
with words as (
      select value as word
      from string_split(@name)
     )
select c.name
from customers c cross apply
     (select count(*) as cnt
      from words w
      where c.name like '%' + c.word + '%'
     ) w
where w.cnt = (select count(*) from words);
```

This uses the `string_split()` functionality available in more recent versions of SQL Server.  There are online versions of the function for older versions.

Comment: Thank you Gordon, I'm going to play with this query to learn something new.
I've not used the string_split before, thank you for that.

Answer (score 1):

This was answered/accepted before I could post and what @sugar2Code posted is how I would do it.

That said, I was unclear if you wanted both the first ***and*** last name needed to be similar or just one of them. What I put together will allow you to decide using a parameter.

```
-- Sample Data
DECLARE @t TABLE (CustomerName VARCHAR(30))
INSERT  @t VALUES('Johny Smith'),('Freddie Roach'),('Mr. Smithers'),('Johnathan Smithe');

-- User Arguments
DECLARE 
  @name         VARCHAR(30) = 'John Smith',
  @partialmatch BIT         = 1;

-- Dynamic Solution
SELECT 
  t.CustomerName,
  FNMatch = SIGN(pos.F),
  LNMatch = SIGN(pos.L)
FROM   @t AS t
CROSS JOIN 
(
  SELECT SUBSTRING(@name,1,f.Mid-1), SUBSTRING(@name,f.Mid+1,8000)
  FROM   (VALUES(CHARINDEX(' ',@name))) AS f(Mid)
) AS f(FName,LName)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (CHARINDEX(f.FName,t.CustomerName), CHARINDEX(f.LName,t.CustomerName))) AS pos(F,L)
WHERE (@partialmatch = 0 AND pos.F*pos.L > 0)
   OR (@partialmatch = 1 AND pos.F+pos.L > 0);
```

When @partialmatch = 1 you get:

```
CustomerName                   FNMatch     LNMatch
------------------------------ ----------- -----------
Johny Smith                    1           1
Mr. Smithers                   0           1
Johnathan Smithe               1           1
```

Setting @partialMatch to 0 will exclude "Mr. Smithers".

Comment: Oh wow! This is much more helpful, thank you so much for this.
I've learned quite a few new things with this solution and have multiple options.
I really appreciate it! Thank you